# Class Html not found error in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I add these packages in my laravel composer.json:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
```

and i add these

```
'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

in  providers and these

```
'Form'=> 'Collective\Html\FormFacade','Html=>'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

in aliases..

But i cant make change like this in my **HTML** file `{{ html::style('/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}` its show **HTML Class Not Found**.

i checked in tinker

```
>>> Form::text('foo')
=> "<input name=\"foo\" type=\"text\">"
```

but its working..any help??

Comment: You use `html` ( html::style...) , but the alias is `Html` not `html`, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Did you do a `composer install`?

Answer (score 1):

Html and Form classes were deprecated from Laravel 5. You can access similar functionality using [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo error. Try this:

```
{{ Html::style('/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [this link](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html), or try this:

Add this in composer.json require section

```
"illuminate/html": "5.*"
```

and run composer update.

Open your config/app.php

add under 'providers' array add this

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

add under 'aliases' array add this

```
'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

and under your blade templates, use like this

```
{!! Html::image('uploads/zami.jpg') !!}
```